# Многоуровневое вертикальное меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Всем привет! У меня появилась задача сделать вертикальное многоуровневое меню (для мобильной версии сайта). Возникла проблема с отображением стрелок, чтобы распахнуть некоторые пункты. Хочется сделать эти стрелки на чистом css и чтобы при клике на них открывалось меню. Некоторые пункты меню нельзя распахнуть. По всем пунктам меню можно кликнуть и пользователь перейдет по ссылке (именно поэтому решено было сделать именно стрелку, чтобы распахнуть меню). Стрелки думаю сделать с помощью псевдоэлемента `:after`.

Интересуют 2 нюанса:

1. Как обработать клик на этот самый псевдоэлемент.
2. Как заставить псевдоэлемент поменять свой вид (например, с плюса на минус - распахнуть, скрыть).

**Меню генерируется автоматически и я могу только прикрутить к нему только css и js.**

На входе я получаю:

```
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
  <li>Пункт 2</li>
  <li>Пункт 3</li>
</ul>
```

*С радостью выслушаю все замечания и предложения по улучшению данного кода. Если считаете, что можно сделать как-то элегантнее - обязательно пишите, буду рад улучшить этот код!*

На данный момент у меня есть вот такая наработка:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu_mobile li a').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').find('ul').eq(0).slideToggle(); 
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_mobile ul {
 margin: 3em 3.5em;
 margin: 7.5vw 8.75vw;
 padding: 0;
}

.menu_mobile li {
 list-style: none;
}

.menu_mobile li a {
 display: block;
 line-height: 30px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px #505050;
 border-radius: 3px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 1em 5px;
}

.menu_mobile li a:hover {
 background: #f2f2f2;
}

.menu_mobile li ul {
 display: none;
}

.menu_mobile ul ul {
 margin: 0;
}

.shown {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu_mobile">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1-2</a>
    <!--Level 2-->
        <ul> 
          <li><a href="#">Level 2-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2-2</a>
          <!--Level 3-->
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1-4</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

При распахивании, подменю прыгает и сразу встает на место, как только распахнулось (очевидно, проблема в объединении отступов). Если кто-то знает, как поправить и вас не затруднит - напишите об этом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема во внешних отступах тега `a` - отступ нужно сделать у `li`

```js
$(function() {
 $("ul li").each(function() {
    this_li = $(this);
    if ($(this_li).find("ul").length > 0) {
      $(this_li).append('<button>v</button>')
    }
  });

  $('.menu_mobile li button').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('li').find('ul').eq(0).slideToggle(); 
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_mobile ul {
 margin: 3em 3.5em;
 margin: 7.5vw 8.75vw;
 padding: 0 2px;
}

.menu_mobile li {
 list-style: none;
    margin: 1em 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.menu_mobile li li {
 list-style: none;
}

.menu_mobile li a {
 display: block;
 line-height: 30px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px #505050;
 border-radius: 3px;
 text-align: center;
}

.menu_mobile li a:hover {
 background: #f2f2f2;
}

.menu_mobile li ul {
 display: none;
}

.menu_mobile ul ul {
 margin: 0;
}

.shown {
 display: block;
}

button{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu_mobile">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1-2</a>
    <!--Level 2-->
        <ul> 
          <li><a href="#">Level 2-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2-2</a>
          <!--Level 3-->
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1-4</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, отличная работа! Осталось что-то придумать с распахиванием меню по стрелочке!

Comment: Кстати, есть решение поинтереснее, если использовать это, то внизу так же прыгает. Я выставил `overflow: hidden` у элемента `li`

Comment: @MarkKhromov Обновил ответ. Добавил раскрытие по кнопке

Comment: Да, про решение с js я знаю, но оно не слишком хорошее, в идеале сделать это на чистом css, а на js только клик обработать, если такое возможно, конечно же. Если завтра к вечеру не будет еще ответом, тогда помечаю ваш как верный! Спасибо!

Comment: Ну, клик по  псевдоэлементу `:after` через js нельзя отследить, т.к. он находится вне DOM-дерева. Поэтому без изменения структуры я не вижу, как это можно сделать без js

Comment: Да, согласен с вами! Помечаю ответ как верный, спасибо!